# 選択範囲の文章中にある特定の文字列の前後に半角スペースを入れたい

Tags: emeditor

いつも利用させていただいております。
ある文章を選択後、選択範囲の中にある全角文字以外の文字列（半角英数・ハイフン・アンダーバー・ピリオド・カンマ・コロンなど）の前後に、半角スペースを追加するマクロを探しております。
例えば次のような文章があった時、

```
あいうえおabc123かきくけこ
さし.hoge-xyz_すせそたちつてと-fugaXXX
http:abc/なにぬねのは$%@!ひふへほ
```

以下のような形に変換できればと思っております。また全角文字以外の文字列が行頭・行末にあった場合、端だけスペースを入れないようにしたいです。

```
あいうえお abc123 かきくけこ
さし .hoge-xyz_ すせそたちつてと -fugaXXX
http:abc/ なにぬねのは $%@! ひふへほ
```

こちらを実現可能なマクロはありますでしょうか…
もしありましたらご教授いただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 次のマクロは試されましたでしょうか? https://www.emeditor.com/files/separatewordsinhalfwidthchars-jsee/ 
https://www.emeditor.com/files/addspacesbetweenfullhalf-jsee/

Comment: ありがとうございます。
このようなマクロを探しておりました。
おかげさまで助かりました。

Comment: あとすみません、解決済みにさせていただければと思いますので回答にも書いていただいてもよろしいでしょうか。お手数をおかけして申し訳ありません。。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

次のマクロをお試しください。

- [半角全角文字の境界に空白を挿入するマクロ](https://www.emeditor.com/files/separatewordsinhalfwidthchars-jsee)
- [漢字と英数字の間に半角スペースをいれるマクロ](https://www.emeditor.com/files/addspacesbetweenfullhalf-jsee)